# Pygame - TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, pygame

I am building a game and I keep on running up against this error. I can't seem to fix it. I believe the problem is either in the function "main" at the bottom or in the classes "Level" and "Level01". If you find there is a way I can improve my code can you also tell me as I am just learning how to build games with OOP.

```
 File "C:/Users/fabma/Documents/PythonGames/RPG/Scroller!.py", line 148, in main
currentLevel.drawer(display)
TypeError: drawer() missing 1 required positional argument: 'display1'
```

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
# Colours + Global constants
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
SIZE = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
# CLASSES
# Block is the common platform


class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, length, height, colour):
        super().__init__()
        # Making image
        self.image = pygame.Surface([length, height])
        self.image.fill(colour)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # Setting Y coordinates
        self.rect.y = HEIGHT * 0.95


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Is it touching the floor?
        self.velocity = 0
        self.standing = True
        # Rendering image and creating some variables
        self.height = 40
        self.length = 40
        self.sprite_x_change = 0
        self.sprite_y_change = 0
        self.image = pygame.Surface([self.height, self.length])
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = HEIGHT * 0.884
        self.level = None
    # Mobility: Left, right, up and stop
    def move_right(self):
        self.sprite_x_change = 15

    def move_left(self):
        self.sprite_x_change = -15

    def move_up(self, platform):
        # Seeing if we hit anything if so then we can jump!
        self.rect.y -= 2
        hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, platform, False)
        if len(hit_list) > 0 or self.rect.bottom >= HEIGHT - Block.height:
            self.change_y = -10

    def stop(self):
        self.sprite_x_change = 0

    def updater(self):
        self.gravity()
        platforms_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platforms, False)
        for blocks in platforms_hit:
            self.sprite_y_change = 0
            # Going down
            if self.sprite_y_change > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = blocks.rect.top
                self.velocity = 0
                self.standing = True
            # Going up
            if self.sprite_y_change < 0:
                self.rect.top = blocks.rect.bottom
                self.standing = False
            if self.sprite_x_change > 0:
                self.rect.right = blocks.rect.left
            if self.sprite_x_change < 0:
                self.rect.left = blocks.rect.right
            if self.sprite_x_change == 0 and self.sprite_y_change == 0:
                self.rect.y = HEIGHT * 0.884

        if self.standing == False:
            self.velocity += 1
        self.rect.x += self.sprite_x_change
        self.rect.y += self.sprite_y_change

    def gravity(self):
        self.sprite_y_change += 0.980665*self.velocity


class Level:
    def __init__(self):
        # Creating groups
        self.sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.all_things = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.platforms = pygame.sprite.Group()

    def drawer(self, display1):
        display1.fill(BLUE)
        self.all_things.draw(display1)


class Level01(Level):
    def __init__(self, player1):
        # Initialise level1
        Level.__init__(self)
        # Level01 things
        block = Block(WIDTH, HEIGHT * 0.05, RED)
        Level.all_things = self.all_things
        self.sprites.add(player1)
        self.platforms.add(block)
        self.all_things.add(player1, block)


def main():
    # Init pygame
    pygame.init()
    # Set screen
    display = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
    # Creating FPS thingy
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    # Making levels  + Player
    player = Player()
    level_1 = Level01(player)
    # Choosing level
    levelList = []
    levelList.append(Level01)
    currentLevelNumber = 0
    currentLevel = levelList[currentLevelNumber]
    # Game loop
    loop = True
    while loop == True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        player.move_right()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        player.move_left()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        player.move_up(currentLevel.platforms)

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and player.sprite_x_change < 0:
                    player.stop()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and player.sprite_x_change > 0:
                    player.stop()
        # Update things
        currentLevel.all_things.update()
        currentLevel.drawer(display)
        # Refresh screen
        clock.tick(30)
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You are also doing strange things in the Level01 `__init__` (assigning static property, not using the `super()` function...)

Comment: ok I will use Super() .__init__() to initialise it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of your level rather than just appending the class itself into your list:

```
levelList.append(Level01)
```

should be...

```
levelList.append(level_1)
```

---

As it stands, you're using the class object rather than an instance of it, which means that the `display` you're passing is getting put into the `self` argument (because the class object won't pass along an instance, because it's not one). Once you're calling it on an instance of the class, the `self` argument will be automatically passed and thus your `display` argument will get passed to the correct spot.

Comment: Actually it should be `level_1` (it's a Level01 instance)

Comment: So I should do levelList.append(level_1). I am confused, sorry for being a noobie at python

Comment: Yep. You created the level_1 instance of the Level01 class, and you should put that in your level list rather than the class itself.